# Редактирование таблицы с вложенным списком параметров

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql, sql

Есть таблица с полями `id`, `parameters`.

В `parameters` хранятся записи в виде `[p1=>1][p2=>2][p3=>3]`.

Мне нужно сделать UPDATE параметров, например, где все записи `[p1=>1]`, и заменить их на `[p1=>2]`.

Как лучше решить эту задачу, минуя кучу запросов к БД?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update t
set  parameters = replace(parameters,'p1=>1','p1=>2')
```

[REPLACE](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_replace_function.html)